# has_and_belongs_to_many STI, restrict to be unique by types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sti

I'm using STI models with has_and_belongs_to_many relations. 
So I have `User` with many `Templates` of different types, like `MainTemplate < Template`; `NotSoMainTemplate < Template`; etc. 
Is there a way to limit each user to have only one `MainTemplate` and only one `NotSoMainTemplate`, and so on for all types?

Comment: what is your requirement? You want association between maintemplate, notsomaintemplate and user or template and user?

Comment: Shweta, first one would be enough.

Answer (score 3):

Let me reiterate the problem statement as I have understood it.

You want `User` to have **at most one** kind of each template. i.e.

- 1 MainTemplate, 1 NotSoMainTemplate, etc.
- You **don't need** a direct relation with `Template` (parent table)
- Each template may be used by more than one user

Based on the above assumption, I would suggest you to do the following:

1. Remove existing `habtm` association between `User` and `Template`
2. Add migrations to add `main_template_id`, `not_so_main_template_id` to `User`
3. Add the following associations:

   ```
   class MainTemplate < Template
       has_many :users
   end

   class NotSoMainTemplate < Templete
       has_many :users
   end

   class class User < ActiveRecord::Base
       belongs_to :main_template
       belongs_to :not_so_main_template
   end
   ```

Comment: But then I can use each template only once. So one more assumption:
 * each template may be used by more than one user

Comment: @alex29 based on this additional assumption I have updated my answer, check

Comment: I was trying to avoid including each template type directly to User model, but seems it'd hard to achieve, both answers to my question suggest similar solutions with hard-coding each type.

Comment: it only works in the console - I can assign template to user, and see it, but nothing really gets saved to the DB's join table.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using STI, you can try `has_one`.

```
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: template_choice
  ...
end

class MainTemplate < Template
  ...
end

class TemplateChoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :template_choice
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one  :main_template, through: :template_choice
  has_one  :not_so_main_template, through: :template_choice
  ...
end
```